# Failing to compare two template template types with fixed number of arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I have a SFINAE template version of `is_same` for comparing template template arguments.
It generally works as expected on both templates with fixed and variadic number of template parameters:

```
namespace eld::util::traits
{
        template<template<typename...> class ATT, template<typename...> class BTT>
        struct is_same_tt : std::false_type
        {
        };

        template<template<typename...> class TT>
        struct is_same_tt<TT, TT> : std::true_type
        {
        };
}

template<typename AT, typename BT, typename CT>
struct fixed_args_number
{
};

template<typename...>
struct variadic_args
{
};

static_assert(eld::util::traits::is_same_tt<fixed_args_number, fixed_args_number>(), "");
static_assert(eld::util::traits::is_same_tt<variadic_args, variadic_args>(), "");
```

But when I compare a template template with a fixed number of template parameters to a member template template, I get `false`, though `true`, when parameters are variadic.

```
template<template<typename...> class TT>
struct designated
{
    template<typename... T>
    using tt_type = TT<T...>;
};

// Does not compile
//static_assert(
//    eld::util::traits::is_same_tt<fixed_args_number, designated<fixed_args_number>::tt_type>(),
//    "");
static_assert(eld::util::traits::is_same_tt<variadic_args, designated<variadic_args>::tt_type>(),
              "");
```

What is the reason? (I only checked it with MinGW64)

---

The initial problem is to find in a type list a designated class that satisfies the condition for the equality of template template types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Neither** should work: GCC has a bug of helpfulness that it considers an alias template to be the same as the underlying template if they’re sufficiently similar.  The fixed/variadic mismatch, while still usable in practice, is enough for it to revert to conforming behavior.

Comment: Is it somehow specified by the standard?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: They’re just different templates (even if all their corresponding *template-id*s name the same type).  What’s there to specify?  There is [CWG1286](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286) on the subject, though.

Comment: Well the link shows that template and alias template (non-member) in this case are considered equivalent. Though I didn't find any mentioning of alias member template equivalence. And I don't see why the wouldn't be, since alias member type IS considered equivalent. Should I maybe modify my qyestion and tag it as language lawyer?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: Types are entities, and type aliases are not, so they are transparent in all cases.  However, templates are also entities, and an alias template is a template—or else you couldn’t pass one as a template template argument—so they’re not transparent.  The issue talks about an example that assumed they were; that doesn’t make it so.  (That the alias template is a member makes no difference, although in your case it’s obviously how you manufacture them.)

Comment: Well, I imagine that two templates (including alias template) should be identical if for every set of template arguments they yield the same type.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: That’s undecidable in general.

Comment: Fair point. The number of possible instantiations is undeterminable